# Custom Model with Firestore

Tags: swift, model, google-cloud-firestore

I have a model which is like this one below

```
struct Package {
    var driverID: String;

    init(data: [String: Any]) {
        self.driverID = data["driverID"] as? String ?? ""
    }

}
```

I want to use it as a Model to map the response to an array of `Packages`
my query is this one:

```
db.collection("packages").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let snapshot = querySnapshot {

        var packages = querySnapshot.flatMap({ (document) in
            return Package(data: document)
        })
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get an error saying: `Cannot convert value of type '([String : Any]) -> Package' to expected argument type '(_) -> _?'`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two wrong places. First, in order to get documents of a snapshot, you should use `snapshot.documents`. Second, in order to get data of a document, you should use `document.data()`. The [code snippet](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-ios/blob/21bb58a13fedb1193f8ab27c2cbc000bf83a817b/firestore/swift/firestore-smoketest/ViewController.swift#L808-L816) on the official website explains everything in this operation. Please try the following code, and debug accordingly.

```swift
db.collection("packages").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let snapshot = querySnapshot {

        var packages = snapshot.documents.compactMap({ (document) in
            return Package(data: document.data())
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` is deprecated and replaced with `compactMap`. Use it like so:

```
db.collection("packages").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let snapshot = querySnapshot {
        var packages = snapshot.documents.compactMap { (document) in
            return Package(data: document.data())
        }
    }
}
```